# Hibernate does not work on Windows Server 2016 Datacenter

Tags: windows, hibernate, windows-server-2016

On Windows Server 2016 I enabled hibernate. It works fine but after a while when I wanted to hibernate it I encountered this message:

> C:\Users\Administrator>shutdown -h
>   The request is not supported.(50)

I enabled and disabled the hibernate but it does not start to work.

Comment: Out of curiosity, *why* do you want to hibernate a computer running a DataCenter edition of Windows? That should be the kind of computers that are running continuously until they die or are replaced. Also, maybe this question has better options of being answered in [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/).

Comment: Try running `powercfg -h on` and then the `shutdown -h` and confirm that Windows Updates, etc. have not indeed disabled it again.